# Zend Framework 2 Paginator Route not working

Tags: zend-framework, pagination

I'm trying to have a paginator split up the number of groups displayed on a page, but for some reason when I try to go to the next set of data or page, it defaults back to the main layout and index page. I'm not sure why this is because I have done this before and it worked fine.

Here is my code:

Route:

```
'groups' => array(
     'type'    => 'Segment',
     'options' => array(
          'route' => '/groups[/:action][/:id]',
          'constraints' => array(
               'id'       => '[0-9]+',
          ), 

          'defaults' => array(
               'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Groups',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
     ),
),



'paginator' => array(
      'type' => 'Segment',
      'options' => array(
          'route' => '/groups/view-more/[page/:page]',
          'constraints' => array(
               'page'     => '[0-9]*',
          ),
       ),

       'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Groups',
             'action'     => 'view-more',
       ),
),
```

Controller -

```
public function viewmoreAction()
{

    $paginator = new Paginator(new DbTableGateway($this->getGroupsTable()));

    $page = 1;

    if ($this->params()->fromRoute('page')) {
        $page = $this->params()->fromRoute('page');
    }

    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int)$page);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);

    return new ViewModel(array('paginator' => $paginator));
}
```

the view:

```
<div class="w3-row">
<div class="w3-col sm-12 w3-center">
<?php if (count($this->paginator) <= 0): ?>
            <p class="w3-center">No more groups found</p>
<?php else: ?>      
    <div class="w3-responsive">
        <table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
            <thead>
                <tr class="w3-white">
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Group Id</th>
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Group Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php 
                    foreach ($this->paginator as $rows):
            ?>
                <tr class="w3-hover-text-red w3-text-black">
                    <td><a href="<?php echo $this->url('members/groups', array('action' => 'group-home', 'id' => $rows['group_id'])); ?>">
                        <?php echo $rows['group_id']; ?>
                    </a></td>
                </tr>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <br><br>
        <div class="w3-right">
            <?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->pagination, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml', array('route' => 'members/paginator')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the paginator view (not sure if I needed to include this but thought I should)

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
<div class="w3-bar">
    <!-- 1st page link -->
    <?php echo $this->firstItemNumber; ?> - <?php echo $this->lastItemNumber; ?> of <?php echo $this->totalItemCount; ?>

    <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->first)); ?>" class="w3-button">First</a> |
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="w3-button w3-disabled">First</span> |
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- previous page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->previos)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>" class="w3-button">&lt; Previous</a> |
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="w3-button w3-disabled">Previous</span> |
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- next page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->next)); ?>" class="w3-button">Next &gt;</a> |
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="w3-button w3-disabled">Next &gt;</span> |
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- last page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->last)); ?>" class="w3-button">Last</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="w3-button w3-disabled">Last</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Module.php code

```
 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
 {

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }


    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }


    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'checkCredentials'));
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'configureLayout'));
    }


    public function checkCredentials(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();

        if (!$matches) {
            return $e;
        }

        $route = $matches->getMatchedRouteName();

        if (0 !== strpos($route, 'members/') && $route !== 'members') {
            return $e;
        }

        $auth_service = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('pblah-auth');

        if (!$auth_service->hasIdentity()) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(302);
            $response->getHeaders()
            ->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRouter()->assemble([], array('name' => 'home/member-login')));
            $response->sendHeaders();
            return $response;
        }

        return $e;
    }


    public function configureLayout(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        if ($e->getError()) {
            return $e;
        }

        $request = $e->getRequest();

        if (!$request instanceof Http\Request || $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $e;
        }

        $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();

        if (!$matches) {
            return $e;
        }

        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $layout = $app->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();

        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');

        $module = strtolower(explode('\\', $controller)[0]);

        if ('members' === $module) {
            $layout->setTemplate('layout/members');
        }
    }


    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Members\Module\EditProfileModel' => function ($sm) {
                    $table_gateway = $sm->get('EditProfileService');
                    $profile = new EditProfileModel($table_gateway);
                    return $profile;
                },

                'EditProfileService' => function ($sm) {
                    $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $result_set_prototype = new ResultSet();
                    $result_set_prototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new EditProfile());
                    return new TableGateway('profiles', $db_adapter, null, $result_set_prototype);
                },

                'Members\Model\ProfileModel' => function ($sm) {
                    $table_gateway = $sm->get('ProfileService');
                    $profile = new ProfileModel($table_gateway, $sm->get('pblah-auth')->getIdentity());

                    return $profile;
                },

                'ProfileService' => function ($sm) {
                    $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    return new TableGateway('profiles', $db_adapter);
                },

                'Members\Model\GroupsModel' => function ($sm) {
                    $table_gateway = $sm->get('GroupsService');
                    $group_model = new GroupsModel($table_gateway, $sm->get('pblah-auth')->getIdentity());

                    return $group_model;
                },

                'GroupsService' => function ($sm) {
                    $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    return new TableGateway('groups', $db_adapter);
                }
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

I've included three screenshots (1 about how the paginator displays, and the second about how it redirects to the wrong page)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KePd.jpg   - 1st

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8N16.jpg   - 2nd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvWkf.jpg   - 3rd

I hope this is enough information, if not, please let me know and I will try my best to add more.

Thanks!

Update -

The route I am trying to get is localhost/members/group/view-more/page/2 and so forth but it redirects to localhost/members (the default layout) if next is clicked on and so forth in the paginator.

Also, here is the complete code for my controller (as requested)

```
 class GroupsController extends AbstractActionController
 {
    protected $groups_service;

    protected $groups_table;


    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array('groups' => $this->getGroupsService()->listGroupsIndex()));
    } 


    public function viewallaction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array('groups' => $this->getGroupsService()->getAllUserGroups()));
    }


    public function viewmoreAction()
    {
        $paginator = new Paginator(new DbTableGateway($this->getGroupsTable(), array('member_id' => $this->getGroupsService()->grabUserId())));

        $page = 1;

        if ($this->params()->fromRoute('page')) {
            $page = $this->params()->fromRoute('page');
        }

        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int)$page);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);

        return new ViewModel(array('paginator' => $paginator));
    }


    public function getgroupsAction()
    {
        $layout = $this->layout();
        $layout->setTerminal(true);

        $view_model = new ViewModel();
        $view_model->setTerminal(true);


        echo json_encode($this->getGroupsService()->listGroups());


        return $view_model;
    }


    public function getgroupmembersonlineAction()
    {
        $layout = $this->layout();
        $layout->setTerminal(true);

        $view_model = new ViewModel();
        $view_model->setTerminal(true);

        try {
            echo json_encode($this->getGroupsService()->getGroupMemsOnline());
        } catch (GroupMembersOnlineException $e) {
            echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $view_model;
    }


    public function grouphomeAction()
    {
        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

        if (0 === $id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('members/groups', array('action' => 'index'));
        }

        if (!$this->getGroupsService()->getGroupInformation($id)) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('members/groups', array('action' => 'index'));
        }

        return new ViewModel(array('group_info' => $this->getGroupsService()->getGroupInformation($id)));
    }


    public function getonegroupmembersonlineAction()
    {
        $layout = $this->layout();
        $layout->setTerminal(true);

        $view_model = new ViewModel();
        $view_model->setTerminal(true);

        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

        try {
            echo json_encode($this->getGroupsService()->getGroupMemsOnline($id));
        } catch (GroupMembersOnlineException $e) {
            echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $view_model;
    }


    public function leavegroupAction()
    {
        $layout = $this->layout();
        $layout->setTerminal(true);

        $view_model = new ViewModel();
        $view_model->setTerminal(true);

        $group_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

        try {
            echo json_encode($this->getGroupsService()->leaveTheGroup($group_id));
        } catch (GroupsException $e) {
            echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $view_model;
    }


    public function creategroupAction()
    {

        $form = new CreateGroupForm();

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form
        ));
    }


    public function cgroupAction() 
    {
        $form = new CreateGroupForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $create_group = new CreateGroup();

            $form->setInputFilter($create_group->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $create_group->exchangeArray($form->getData());

                try {
                    if ($this->getGroupsService()->createNewGroup($create_group)) {
                        $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage("Group was created successfully!");

                        return $this->redirect()->toUrl('create-group-success');
                    } 
                } catch (GroupsException $e) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage((string)$e->getMessage());

                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('create-group-failure');
                }
            } else {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("Invalid form. Please correct this and try again.");

                return $this->redirect()->toUrl('create-group-failure');
            }
        }
    }


    public function postgroupmessageAction()
    {

    }


    public function postgroupeventAction()
    {

    }


    public function joingroupAction()
    {
        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

        $form = new JoinGroupForm();

        return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'id' => $id));
    }


    public function jgroupAction()
    {

        $form = new JoinGroupForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $join_group = new JoinGroup();


            $form->setInputFilter($join_group->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());


            if ($form->isValid()) { 
                $join_group->exchangeArray($form->getData());

                try {
                    if (false !== $this->getGroupsService()->joinTheGroup($_POST['group_id'], $join_group)) {
                        $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage("Request to join group sent.");

                        return $this->redirect()->toUrl('join-group-success');
                    }
                } catch (GroupsException $e) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage((string)$e->getMessage());

                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('join-group-failure');
                }
            } else {
                $messages = $form->getMessages();

                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("Invalid form. Please correct this and try again.");

                return $this->redirect()->toUrl('join-group-failure'); 
            } 
        }
    }


    public function joingroupsuccessAction()
    {

    }


    public function joingroupfailureAction()
    {

    }


    public function viewgroupsAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array('groups' => $this->getGroupsService()->listAllGroups()));
    }


    public function creategroupsuccessAction()
    {

    }


    public function creategroupfailureAction()
    {

    }



    public function getGroupsService()
    {
        if (!$this->groups_service) {
            $this->groups_service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Members\Model\GroupsModel');
        }

        return $this->groups_service;
    }


    public function getGroupsTable()
    {
        if (!$this->groups_table) {
            $this->groups_table = new TableGateway('group_members', $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
        }

        return $this->groups_table;
    }
```

Comment: I see that you have different names of actions in your controller('viewmore') and module.config('view-more'). Also you should check your paginator.phtml. Look at manual:https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html.

Comment: I can't use view-more in my controller's actions. I was trying to use - to keep it separated.

Comment: This was working in another paginator I had made, not sure why it isn't with this one.

Comment: Can you show us the entire code of the controller?

Comment: just added it to the post

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you have a type-o in your configuration. Depending on the logic in the rest of your controller it may decide to redirect or forward to another action, resulting in the incorrect page being shown (screenshot 3).

The name of your controller action is `viewmore` but in the route configuration you have `view-more`. This action can not be found. Either rename the action to `viewMore` or change the configured action in your route to `viewmore`:

## Solution 1:

Change the name of the action. The name of the action will be 'view-more' in configurations, routes etc.

```
public function viewMoreAction()
{

    $paginator = new Paginator(new DbTableGateway($this->getGroupsTable()));

    $page = 1;

    if ($this->params()->fromRoute('page')) {
        $page = $this->params()->fromRoute('page');
    }

    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int)$page);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);

    return new ViewModel(array('paginator' => $paginator));
}
```

## Solution 2:

Change the name in the config so the action is correctly matched.

```
'paginator' => array(
      'type' => 'Segment',
      'options' => array(
          'route' => '/groups/view-more/[page/:page]',
          'constraints' => array(
               'page'     => '[0-9]*',
          ),
       ),

       'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Groups',
             'action'     => 'viewmore',
       ),
),
```

By the way, to make your life easier you could start referencing classes by their name like this: `Members\Controller\Groups::class`. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) about the class keyword. This way your editor will keep track of the classes usages.

## Edit

The routes you created are called `groups` and `paginator`. In your code you're calling the route by `members/groups` and `members/paginator`. I believe that is incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still doing the issue I've had (screenshot 3). Not sure why anymore..

Comment: But you marked this as accepted? You could start another question with some more details, I'm sure stackoverflow can help you out.

Comment: Alright, no problem. Can you maybe give us more details about the problem? Can you detect a redirect? What url do you expect and what url is the result? What is the code in your `Module.php`?

Comment: I added the code in module.php and the route I am trying to get, hope that is enough, if not, please let me know :)

Comment: Try and change the route in your view from `members/paginator` to `paginator`.

Comment: well, now it says page not found, so at least that's something.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix the issue? Was the 404 related to this question?

Comment: no I never could figure it out, sort of just gave up on it.